# How to customize Django TimeField()?

Tags: django-forms, django-widget

There is a restaurant table reservation app which I am trying to make that has `DateField()` and `TimeField()` fields.

Now suppose there is a table booking for `XX:xx` time and `XX/XX/XXXX` date. Now in the rendered HTML form, I want the reserved time to not be available anymore. How can I do that?